# How to fuse inertial and optical tracking data with an error-state kalman filter, and provide pose estimations for both update types?

Tags: filters, gaussian, kalman-filter

I am searching for an error-state kalman filter that is able to fuse inertial and optical tracking data but provides pose estimates for both optical and inertial updates.

Currently I am using the following approach: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.02508.pdf

- Chapter 5.2: The error-state Kalman filter explained
- Chapter 6: Fusing IMU with complementary sensory data

**Prediction**

$\delta \hat{x} \leftarrow  F_x(x,u_{m}) \delta \hat{x}$

$\delta \hat{x}$ is zero and cannot be used for prediction (see Reset)

$P \leftarrow F_x P F_x^T + F_i Q_i F_i^T$

**Observation**

$K = P H^T (HPH^t + V)^{-1}$

$P \leftarrow (I - K H ) P$

$\delta \hat{x} \leftarrow K (z - h(\hat{x}_t))$

**Injection of the error state**

$x \leftarrow x \oplus \delta \hat{x}$

The symbol $\oplus$ stands for a generic composition.

**Reset of the error-state**

$\delta \hat{x} \leftarrow 0$

$P \leftarrow G P G^T$

During the prediction phase the acceleration and angular velocity provided by the IMU is used to predict the covariance matrix of the nominal state. But the approach does not provide a prediction of the nominal state during the prediction phase. I get around 1k inertial updates per second and 100 optical updates per second. Therefore I get smoothed pose estimates for optical updates but no pose estimations during IMU updates.

Is there a way to modify this approach to provide pose estimates for IMU updates too?

I tried to just integrate the IMU data and inject it into the nominal state for IMU updates but this leaves me with drifts and an overall more noisy signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eskf presented in the linked approach is able to fuse and predict updates during the integration phase. I used the time stamp of the last optical tracking update as well which lead to wrong time spans and therefore a distorted signal. I still have drifts but i guess that is because of the use of the Euler integration. I will have a look at the Runge-Kutta integration method and see if this fixes the drifts.